# swift throws python errors from terminal

Tags: swift

I'm getting an error whenever I try to start swift related to python.  How do I fix this?

> bash-3.2$ swift --version
>   Apple Swift version 4.1 (swiftlang-902.0.48 clang-902.0.37.1)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
>   bash-3.2$ swift
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in 
>       import weakref
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in 
>       from _weakref import (
>   ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I get the same error, because the swift REPL uses the python interpreter which homebrew installed at `/usr/local/bin/python`.

To avoid this you can

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
swift
```

or

```
PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH swift
```

Comment: Yah Apple for doing the idiotic thing of not compiling a full path into their toolchain.

Comment: I have the same error except the python referenced is anaconda's i.e. "/Users/liyuan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/weakref.py" instead of "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/weakref.py"

Comment: how to change in this case?

Comment: You can also add this to `~/.bash_profile` to avoid changing my PATH: `alias swift='PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH swift'`, worked fine here